# Find the value of $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \big(1+\frac{1}{k^s}\big)$

Tags: infinite-product

I am attempting to find values to the family of products given by
$$p(s)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bigg(1+\frac{1}{k^s}\Bigg)$$
where $s\in \mathbb{C}$ and the real part of $s$ is greater than $1$. In particular the values of $p(2)$ and $p(3)$ are
$$p(2)=\frac{\sinh{\pi}}{\pi}$$
$$p(3)=\frac{\cosh{\Big(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi\Big)}}{\pi}$$
by using Wolfram: Alpha.

Firstly, I would like to know if there is a method which allows $p(s)$ to be written in a closed form for any $s\in \mathbb{C}$. Otherwise, can someone explain how to find the values of $p(2)$ and $p(3)$ shown above?

Comment: For $s=2$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598805/weierstrass-product-form. The general theory behind these products is [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem). One should also be able to do $s=2^n$ in general IIRC.

Comment: If you combine Weierstrass product formula for $\sin(\pi x)$ with an explicit factorization of $1 + 1/k^{2^n}$ into factors of the form $1 + c/k^2$ you should end up with a closed form for $s = 2^n$ like $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1 + \frac{1}{k^{2^n}}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \frac{\sin(\pi z_k)}{\pi z_k}$$ where $z_k = e^{\pi i\cdot \frac{2k-1}{2^n}}$.

Comment: To save others the search, the Dirichlet series has coefficients https://oeis.org/A045778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For integers at least:

Following in the lines of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785975), we can write

$$\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{P(k)}{k^s},$$

where $P(x)=(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_s)$, as

$$\prod_{j=1}^s \frac{\Gamma(N-\alpha_j)}{\Gamma(N)\Gamma(1-\alpha_j)}.$$

Then, using the lemma also described in that answer that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\Gamma(N+\alpha_i)}{\Gamma(N+\beta_i)}=1$$

if $\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i=\sum_{i=1}^N \beta_i$, the terms involving $N$ cancel out in the limit and we get

$$\prod_{j=1}^s \Gamma(1-\alpha_j)^{-1}.$$

Using that $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)\Gamma(x-1)$, we can write this as

$$(-1)^{s+1}\prod_{j=1}^s \Gamma(-\alpha_j)^{-1}.$$

This doesn't seem to have a nice closed form (or at least not one [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+from+k%3D1+to+infty+(1%2B1%2Fk%5E5)) can find for $s=5$), but we can evaluate it for $s=2$ as follows, by noting that

$$\Gamma(i)\Gamma(-i)=i\Gamma(i)\Gamma(1-i)=\frac{i\pi}{\sin(i\pi)}=\frac{\pi}{\sinh \pi},$$

which gives your result. For $s=3$, the product becomes the reciprocal of

\begin{align*}
\prod_{\omega^3=1}\Gamma(\omega)
&=\Gamma(\omega)\Gamma(\overline{\omega})\\
&=|\Gamma(\omega)|^2\\
&=\frac{|\Gamma(1+\omega)|^2}{|\omega|^2}\\
&=\left|\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right|^2\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}.
\end{align*}